# Weird behavior of BitmapFontCache and BitmapFont generating?

Tags: fonts, libgdx

[image]

As you can see, the numbers are not shown correctly. They are supposed to look just like: 173 and 15.4 , but they don't. Why is that happening? I really have no idea. It only happes with the bigger font, not with the smaller ones.

Moreover, that bug only appears on smartphones with a higher resolution. It does not appear when I launch the app as a desktop applicaion, or on a phone with a lower resolution (480 x 800).

I am generating the fonts on the fly with a TTF font.
My code:

Generating:

```
public static BitmapFont generateFont(int size, String fontPath) {
    float scale = 1.0f * Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / Game.WIDTH;

    if(scale < 1)
        scale = 1;

    FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter params = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();
    generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal(fontPath));

    params.size = (int) (size * scale);

    BitmapFont font = generator.generateFont(params);
    font.getData().setScale((float) (1.0 / scale));
    font.getRegion().getTexture().setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Linear, Texture.TextureFilter.Linear);

    dispose();

    return font;
}
```

Then I generate the font:

```
FONT_115 = FontGenerator.generateFont(115, FONT_TTF_DEFAULT);
```

Then I make a text with this font:

```
layout = new GlyphLayout(font, "");
fontCache = new BitmapFontCache(font);
layout.setText(font, text);
fontCache.setText(layout, position.x - layout.width / 2, position.y);
```

So my question:
Why is text in a bigger font not show correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following fixed that problem:

```
FreeTypeFontGenerator.setMaxTextureSize(FreeTypeFontGenerator.NO_MAXIMUM);
```

However, there are some artifacts (see picture).

[image]